# How to create a View in Sql Server Database Project without creating reffenrenced tables

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-project

I am trying to add a view to a Sql Server Database Project in VS 2015. The view references two tables, which are NOT defined in the project. 
So, my view DDL looks like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[My_View]
    AS select a.Name, b.Name
from [dbo].[TableA] a
join [dbo].[TableB] b
 on a.Ref = b.Ref
```

Neither TableA, nor TableB exists in the Database project, but they both exist in the target database. I don't want to add them to the project, because they belong to different application and should not be controlled by this particular project as it only defines a subset of tables/views in the target database. 
I can't compile my project because of the error:
`Error:  SQL71501: View: [dbo].[My_View] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[TableA].` (And some further errors from the same root cause)

I tried adding a reference to master db - no luck.

Is there any way to circumvent this error? Or maybe somehow add a reference to the TableA and TableB to the project without actual DDL defining these tables?

Comment: how do you expect to resolve the references later ?

Comment: @McNets - I am confident that TableA and TableB are always in the target database - there is another script that controls that (not VS Sql server project).

Comment: I believe the solution is to: 1. Create a separate database project "A", containing these tables; 2. Create a reference to this in your project. 3. Never deploy or change project A, just use it as a "stub"